# Can't copmare strings PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have array `$commentArray` that reads data from file, and it have elements like

```
some data1    
some data2
...
--------------- (it's like a break point)
some data
some data
...
--------------- 
...
```

So here i'm do some action on my array

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($commentArray); $i++)
        {   
            $arrayElem .= $commentArray[$i];

            echo($arrayElem);
            echo("<br>");

            $arrayElem = "";

            if($commentArray[$i] == "---------------")
            {   
                /*
                $commentArraySorted[$iterator] = $arrayElem;
                $arrayElem = "";

                $iterator++;
                $i++;
                */
                echo("STOP<br>");
            }
        }
```

but the problem is that compiler don't see string `---------------` because the code block

```
if($commentArray[$i] == "---------------")
        {   
            /*
            $commentArraySorted[$iterator] = $arrayElem;
            $arrayElem = "";

            $iterator++;
            $i++;
            */
            echo("STOP<br>");
        }
```

don't work, but when i echoing array elements, the element `---------------` is echoing too.

Comment: how do you fill $commentArray from a file?

Comment: `$commentArray = file("recordsComment.txt");`

Comment: add 2nd argument  - `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES`

Comment: It helps, thanks very much)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to splash58. The answer is to add 2nd argument `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` in `$commentArray = file("recordsComment.txt");`